# XSLT Multi XML Tags

Tags: xml, xslt

Good day. I am currently learning XSLT 2.0. I would like to pull a data that comes from multi similar tags. Like the one below

Here is my XSLT :

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root1/root2">
     <xsl:for-each select="a1 | b1">
           <xsl:value-of select="c1">
           <xsl:value-of select="a1">
           <xsl:value-of select="b1">
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Input XML:

```
<root1>
    <root2>
        <a1>Car1</a1>
        <a1>Car2</a1>
        <a1>Car3</a1> 
        <b1>Red</b1>
        <b1>Blue</b1>
        <b1>Black</b1>
        <c1>Name</c1>
    </root2>
</root>
```

Desired Output:

> Name Car1 Red
>
> Name Car2 Blue
>
> Name Car3 Black

I could not even pull up Name with my XSLT

How do I pair up a1 with the correct b1?

Any suggestion?

Comment: The question is confusing. Is the "XML" you show us the input? If yes, you will not be able do anything with it: element names cannot start with a digit.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Ahh. Sorry about that. Yes it is the input, I am converting it to text. Did I miss anything else?

Comment: The logic of the desired transformation is still not clear. Are the elements really numbered like that, or is that just an example?

Comment: @michael.hor257k just an example. I want to add C to every a1 and b1 pair. the pairing is already arrange in order in XML

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root1">
    <xsl:for-each select="root2">
        <xsl:for-each select="a1">
            <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
            <xsl:value-of select="string-join((../c1, ., ../b1[$i], '&#10;'), ' ')"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```